# Rails + Rspec: How to stub a record so that it's marked as invalid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Purchase` model with a method:

```
def set_status_to_in_progress!
  self.update_attributes!(status: IN_PROGRESS)
end
```

And a failing rspec test:

```
context "self is invalid" do
  it "raises an error" do
    purchase = Purchase.new
    purchase.stub(:valid?).and_return(:false)
    expect { purchase.set_status_to_in_progress! }.to raise_error
  end
end
```

which returns

```
Failures:

      1) Purchase#set_status_to_in_progress! self is invalid raises an error
         Failure/Error: expect { purchase.set_status_to_in_progress! }.to raise_error
           expected Exception but nothing was raised
         # ./spec/models/purchase_spec.rb:149:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I thought stubbing `valid?` would be enough to make the ActiveRecord `update_attributes!` method raise an error? How would I make it raise?

Answer (score 4):

Try changing :false to false

```
purchase.stub(:valid?).and_return(false)
```

or

```
purchase.should_receive(:valid?).and_return(false)
```

otherwise you can stub any instance of Purchase

```
Purchase.any_instance.should_receive(:valid?).and_return(false)
```

Comment: So the issue was because I had `...and_return(:false)` a symbol and not `false` the boolean. So `purchase.stub(:valid?).and_return(false) works

Answer (score 0):

This is the **DEFINITIVE** guide to successfully test validation errors when there is no way to simulate with real validations on your model. In my case the SupportRequest model does not have any validation but I want to test like there is one, so what I did first was create a double then make it so it return false when trying to update, then added errors to the record and last test that the records were there. :)

```
describe "with invalid data" do
  before do
    the_double = instance_double("SupportRequest", id: support_request.id)
    active_model_errors = ActiveModel::Errors.new(the_double).tap { |e| e.add(:description, "can't be blank") }
    allow_any_instance_of(SupportRequest).to receive(:update_attributes).and_return(false)
    allow_any_instance_of(SupportRequest).to receive(:errors).and_return(active_model_errors)
    put "/api/support_requests/#{support_request.id}",
      params: {
        data: {
          type: "support-requests",
          attributes: {}
        }
      },
      headers: authenticated_header(support_agent)
  end

  it "should not create a new support_request" do
    expect_json(errors: [
      {
        source: {
          pointer: "/data/attributes/description"
        },
        detail: "can't be blank"
      }
    ])
  end
  it "should return status code (422)" do
    expect_status(422)
  end
end
```